# Why I am seeing every letter capitalized while browsing in chrome?

Tags: google-play-store, chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android, fonts

I'm using android 5.1(Gionee p5 mini)  and chrome 58.0.3029.83
While I am using chrome i am seeing every letter capitalized. Even i got the same thing on play store and also Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Did you observe this with an another keyboard app?

Comment: @Firelord       No I have the same problem with almost every keyboard I have used (Default Keyboard, TouchPal, Gboard)